# Как отследить открытие нового приложения либо смену активного окна?

Tags: c#

Как отследить открытие нового приложения либо смену активного окна?

Comment: Смену активного окна чужого приложения?

Comment: Да, смену окна чужого приложения. т.е. в системе вообще. Сейчас рассматриваю как вариант импортировать GetForegroundWindow() и по таймеру проверять какое приложение активно.

Answer (score 3):

Средствами .NET нельзя получить информацию о смене активного окна или создании нового окна - нужно использовать глобальные хуки. Отслеживание активаций идет через хук CBTProc (устанавливается SetWindowsHookEx). В этом хуке нужно смотреть на события:

- HCBT_ACTIVATE
- HCBT_CREATEWND

Нужно будет создать библиотеку для хуков, установить ее в систему и по активации хука слать сообщение в приложение на .NET. Ну, а чтобы отлавливать свои сообщения в .NET, нужно переопределить WndProc.

Comment: В .Net нашел возможность посредством WMI отследить открытие нового приложения через объект ManagementEventWatcher.

Comment: @Dim WMI тут не причем. WMI - это отдельная песня :)

Answer (score 1):

Статья [Win32 API. Hooks](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/win32/win32-hooks.html) поможет вам разобраться, как это делать грамотно.